# Not showing django application in admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I created poll aplication in Django. Here is `admin.py` code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from poll.models import Question, Choice

class ChoiceInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['question_text']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date']})
    ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]

admin.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

Also, I added 'poll' to `INSTALLED_APPS`. Now I have no urls and views for my poll application. Maybe the problem is with it?
Also I have other application 'article', I did the same as with poll, and `article` has appeared in admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `admin.site.register` instead of just `admin.register`